# How do I display the first 2 decimals of a number only using casts?

Tags: java, casting

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please input a decimal number:");
    double a = scan.nextDouble();  
    int b = (int)a; 
    double answer = (a - b);    

System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
```

This is what I have but as is written it would display all of the decimal portion, I only want the first 2 decimals. Meaning I would input 7.239485 and I would get 23 as the output. Also when I do put in only 2 decimal places I get a very close appoximation. Meaning 7.23 would return 0.229989898999 or something like that.

Comment: Always remember that floating point math is not 100% accurate!

Comment: Multiply the difference by 100.

Comment: Why do you want to do it "only using casts"?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
double x = 7.232323;
int y = (int) (x % 1 * 100);
```

Comment: You might want to round that.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way for this would be to use DecimalFormat:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

```
new DecimalFormat("0.##").format(answer)
```

an easier way would be:

```
((double) Math.round(answer * 100)) / 100
```

or implement `Math.round()` yourself (which is sort of ugly since these methods already exist)

```
int answer_round = ((double) (int)(answer * 100)) / 100;
if (answer*100 - (int)(answer*100) >= 0.5) { answer_round += 0.01; }
```

Comment: added a 3rd option ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Davide
 */
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number");
        double b = a.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(findDecimal(b, 2));
    }

    public static int findDecimal(double number, int decimal) {
        return (int) (number % 1 * Math.pow(10, decimal));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please input a decimal number:");
    double a = scan.nextDouble();  
    int b = (int)a; 
    double answer = (double)(int)(a*100 - b*100)/100;   

System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
```